# Implementation of tryCatch in time-series prediction in R

Tags: r, try-catch, time-series

I have some time series sales data and I want to forecast sales for a given horizon. I use Holt-Winters, ets, Neural Networks and some other methods and then hybridize their results. However, depending on the Holt Winters doesn't always work. I have written two functions, one named `forecastWithHoltWinters` and the other is `forecastWithoutHoltWinters` and may objective is that is if `forecastWithHoltWinters` yields an error, then I need to run the `forecastWithoutHoltWinters`. They both have the same inputs, that are `salesdata` (time series data) and `horizon` (a scalar), and the output is `salesforecast` for the given `horizon` periods.

Checking the most upvoted answer in [How to write trycatch in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193779/how-to-write-trycatch-in-r) , I coded as given below:

```
forecastWithHoltWinters <- function(salesdata, horizon)
{
     salesforecast <- tryCatch(
     {
        #Lots of lines that forecastWithHoltWinters does
     }, error <- function (salesdata, horizon)
     {
         salesforecast = forecastWithoutHoltWinters(salesdata, horizon)
         return (salesforecast)
     }
return (salesforecast)
}
```

I can see that things are so wrong here but I cannot seem to adapt my problem to `tryCatch()`. I have gone though http://mazamascience.com/WorkingWithData/?p=912, too. I'll adjust the warnings later, but first I need to deal with errors.

How do I do this?

Edit: I worked on it for a while, there aren't any sourcing errors. Yet, the `error <- function (salesdata, horizon)` won't transfer the inputs to the `forecastWithoutHoltWinters` function, hence the function isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

Just change your error function to:

```
error <- function (e)
     {print(e)#comment out if you dont want to print error
      salesforecast = forecastWithoutHoltWinters(salesdata, horizon)
      return (salesforecast)
     }
```

This I think should work. :)

Comment: It is actually `forecastWithoutHoltWinters` function, I mistyped here. I edited it. Thank you.

Comment: The tryCatch code looks fine to me. Your code will encounter problem only when forecastWithoutHoltWinters function will fail. If that does not happen, then your code should run.

Comment: Maybe I should elaborate on the error. The part where I say `#Lots of lines that forecastWithHoltWinters does` starts with a variable definition, `clforecast=matrix(,nrow=5,ncol=horizon)` and the error is in the first letter. It is not about braces.

Comment: Got it! It's not about braces, but it's about brackets. Thank you.

Comment: However, it still won't run and `error <- function (salesdata, horizon)` won't take inputs. Hence `forecastWithoutHoltWinters` isn't working.

Comment: I edited my answer. Please check if it works. If yes, Please upvote answer. :)

Comment: Thank you, it partly worked. I'm not getting any source errors but the `forecastWithoutHoltWinters` isn't taking any inputs.